# My website's cache stopped working randomly

Tags: php, caching, browser-cache

On my website some user started to experience very slow page loading on PC but fine on cellphone. I tried going into Incognito mode, it was very slow even thought before (2-4 weeks) I went on my site on Incognito mode and it was working fine. I then cleared my cache, and now even my normal chrome browsing is slow.

Do anyone know what could have cause this? No one touched the code for a month.

Also if anyone have a suggestion on how I might be able to fix this, it would be very appreciated.

Thank you,

Jessie

Comment: You can start with opening page inspector (F12), going into Network tab and seeing what assets are taking the longest to load

Comment: You should also check for server's resources, bandwidth, CPU/mem usage. Is it your own server or a shared hosting? If it is the latter, you should speak with their admins

Comment: Yes! Thank you didn't know how useful the Network tab was, went there, found a gap in the waterfall which matches the unusual delay (20 seconds), started putting in comment part of codes in that gap and found it! (captchme-interstitial-min.js for those who run into that problem) Thank you!

Comment: Glad the issue was resolved. You can upvote my comments too if I helped you :P

Comment: Sadly I don't have enough reputation to upvote :(

Comment: Oh, right, completely forgot about that, nevermind then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering just to mark it as answered.

The problem was a .js link which wasn't valid anymore (captchme-interstitial-min.js) that was in my header. removed it from the code an now everything is good!

Thanks to p0358 for the big help